# Query works in SQL Server but not in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I wrote a query in SQL Server and it ran without a problem. Here's the query with the names changed for privacy reasons.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 (nolock)
LEFT JOIN table2 (nolock)
ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE table1.Date = '2021-03-05' AND table1.ID = '120';
```

This works fine and pulls 30k rows. I have created an ODBC connection using the `DBI` and `odbc` packages to the server in R. I can run queries from R just fine. I've run many without an issue. For example, this runs with no errors:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, believeNRows = FALSE, "
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM table1 (nolock);
")
```

But when I include a `LEFT JOIN`, then the query in R fails and returns an error.

Here's the same query in R:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, believeNRows = FALSE, "
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 (nolock)
    LEFT JOIN table2 (nolock)
    ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    WHERE table1.Date = '2021-03-05' AND table1.ID = '120';
")
```

I'm working in VSCode so the error message isn't very informative:

> Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) :    attempt to
> apply non-function

Based on some other answers, I included a couple of extra options in the query, but they didn't help:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, believeNRows = FALSE, "
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM table1 (nolock)
    LEFT JOIN table2 (nolock)
    ON table1.ID = table2.ID
    WHERE table1.Date = '2021-03-05' AND table1.ID = '120';
")
```

Does anyone have any idea why this perfectly good query isn't working when passed to SQL Server from within R?

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK` against all of your tables? Do you understand what `NOLOCK` does? Why not just change the isolation level? I suggest reading [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Larnu It was suggested to me by IT but I'll check the link now. The inclusion of `nolock` doesn't affect the error outcome though.

Comment: No, but it will affect the reliability of your results.

Comment: Maybe `conn` isn't pointing to the database you think it is. Can you `select top 10 * from table2` independently?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, I can pull data from each separately. It's only when I use `JOIN` that I get an error.

Comment: It might be helpful to see a more instructive error message. Are you able to run the same connection and code in `Rterm` or RStudio? (I didn't realize VScode masked error messages, that can definitely be frustrating.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks to your comment, I solved by problem! I ran the code in Rconsole as you suggested and got the same masked error message. Seemed weird so I did some research and found a fix, reran the code and got a useful error message that solved the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one else has this problem in the future, there were two hurdles in my way. First, relative to @r2evans comment, my error messages were being masked. Per [a readr github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1371), I reinstalled the `cli` package and started getting unmasked error messages. Reran my code and received this error:

```
Error:
! Column names `ID1` and `Col1` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "ID1" at locations 3 and 72.
  * "Col1" at locations 45 and 75.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Turns out, the `SQL` call brings back all columns and SSMS removes the duplicate columns automatically. R, on the other hand, does not. So I changed my `SELECT` clause to choose the specific columns I wanted and the code worked.